# Multi language support in contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I have created a contract using solidity which has a comment field. I want to provide multi language support  so that user can insert and retrieve comment in any language.

Please suggest how we can achieve this feature?

Comment: Can you please post more details?

Comment: I want to insert and retrieve Chinese language.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using just a single `string` to store the comment, you will have to use an `array`, `struct` or `mapping` to store all the translations. For example,  you could create a mapping of two-letter language codes to the versions of the comment in that language:

`mapping (bytes2 => string) languageCodeToComment;`

Now, you can add a comment in multiple langauges:

`languageCodeToComment["EN"] = "This is the English comment!";`

`languageCodeToComment["NL"] = "Dit is het Nederlandse bericht!";`

`languageCodeToComment["FY"] = "Dit is yn it Frysk!";`

Comment: Thanks Jesse, How to insert and get comment in Chinese language?

Comment: @vaibhav You can use the same technique: `languageCodeToComment["ZH"] = "漢字";`

Comment: I understand it. but when i  fetch Chinese value, it returns hexa value. how to convert hexa to chinese ?

Comment: @vaibhav Can you paste here what it returns? I hadn't tested non-ASCII characters before, but it seems to work fine. Check out this test contract I just deployed: https://etherscan.io/address/0x6df5df1583fa3f31d7599503d56b4fe6925e0cb9#readContract

Comment: @vaibhav Read this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28344/should-i-use-bytes-or-string-always, solidity stores strings as sequence of bytes. They suggest converting your string to utf-8 encoding before storing, and decoding from utf-8 to your string type. For example javascript strings are utf-16 so you have to convert to utf-8 before storing them.